# After an Intent takes the user to the homescreen, what else can your application do?

Tags: android, android-intent, homescreen

When would you need an Intent that takes you to the home screen? Because doesn't that mean you no longer have control of the application?

For example, what could you, as a developer, do after the following code was executed:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Comment: I'm trying to get info about the way the user interacts with their device. i.e opens another app/opens folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a much trickier question that you probably think.  First of all, in real life you would not normally do that.  If you are finished your activity, you call its finish() method.  The android system returns you to the activity you called your activity from, which if you launched it from the home screen would be your homescreen.  But if you launched it from some other application, like looking at a map of the address of one of your contacts for example, you would be returned to your contact app when you "finish()" on the map activity.

When you launch an activity with an intent, depending on the exact nature of that activity, you may open a new instance of that activity in the process your activity is running in, or you might just bring to the front a different process already running that application/activity.  In the case of the home screen, I don't know exactly what happens because I don't know how the home screen is programmed as an application/activity, and how it is declared in the manifest.

For giggles, I put your lines of code in the onCreate() of the main activity of one of my applications.  I got fairly erratic behavior.  The intent definitely threw me out of my app and seems to have destroyed the process my application was running in in the process.  (At least in eclipse, it terminated the ADB connection so I could no longer see what was happening with it.)  When I went back to my main activity from the homescreen, it would sometimes go back to the main screen of my app, sometimes to the secondary screen of my app, and sometimes just pop back to the homescreen again.  I imagine the other lines of code calling intents for my secondary app were part of the "state" of my app somehow, that somehow going back it would somehow come in after launching the home activity.

Obviously I am waffling around here.  I'll leave this to others who might put an answer in the context of something that would really benefit from calling an intent to launch a homescreen, rather than using "finish()" to get away from the activity.